# travel from Gothenburg C to Copenhagen airport (CPH)

Tags: customs-and-immigration, trains, sweden, denmark

I have a return flight to Canada from the Copenhagen airport (CPH) at 12:35pm on July 1st, 2017 and am currently staying in Gothenburg. I have booked a ticket with Öresundståg departing from Gothenburg Central Station at 6:55am on July 1st and arriving at the Copenhagen airport at 10:13am on July 1st. If everything goes according to plan, I will have enough time to check-in my return flight and board the plane.

I know that there is currently border control by Sweden for trains entering Sweden from Denmark.

Q1) If I am entering Denmark from Sweden, is there any similar border control at any point during the trip that would make the duration of the train ride longer?

The [Öresundståg website](http://www.oresundstag.se/en/traffic-information/border-controls/) says that

> Traveling from Sweden to Denmark
>
> When traveling from Sweden to Denmark there are no border or ID
>   controls. The trains run according to schedule, with the exception of
>   the reduction to one departure every 20 minutes even during peak
>   hours.

Q2) Is this really accurate?

Q3) If there is indeed a border control for train rides from Sweden to Denmark, how much time should I expect it to add to the trip?

I noticed today on the [Öresundståg website](http://www.oresundstag.se/en/) a notice saying

> Disruptions in traffic between Halmstad and Falkenberg 2017-06-29
>   10:45
>
> Due to an accident the Öresundståg between Halmstad and Falkenberg is
>   cancelled. Replacement buses will cover the distance, time for travel
>   will increase.

2) Is this a temporary notice, only applicable to the day June 29, 2017 (i.e., today)? Or should I expect that my train on July 1, 2017 will also be delayed?

In short, my concern is to arrive on time at the Copenhagen airport to be able to catch my flight back to Canada. There are buses that will leave Gothenburg Central Station, but will arrive way too early at the airport. I prefer the train but am a bit worried about unexpected delays (or expected ones) during the train ride.

Comment: Note that with Øresundståg, you should be able to catch an earlier train if that appeases your peace of mind.  I believe those tickets are not bound to specific trains.

Comment: @gerrit The train 6:55 is the first departure. Taking an earlier train would mean to travel the evening before and spend the night on the airport.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Oh, it's a Saturday.  On weekdays the first train [departs 05:25](http://tagtidtabeller.resrobot.se/tidtabell/tag100_9730.pdf) (with changes in Halmstad and Malmö)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are no border checks from Sweden to Denmark at all, so the train won't be delayed for that reason.

According to [Hallandstrafiken](http://www.hallandstrafiken.se/), this incident affects **northbound** Services only.

So you'll be **completely** fine, barring other complications

Comment: Thank you. I called and asked about the notice, and the rep said that it only applies for today and not any other day.